# CUPS: Share printer with generic driver

Tags: cups

I've installed a printer with a proprietary driver and shared it on the network (with Avahi).

Other computers detect the printer automatically, but can't print because they can't find a matching driver.

Printing with a generic driver works fine (as the sharing computer already has the proprietary driver), but it's not configured automatically.

What can I change on the sharing computer to get other computers to automatically choose a generic driver?

Comment: The answer to your question is depending on the versions of CUPS you are using. So.... (1) Which OS and which version of CUPS is running on the computer which has the proprietary driver installed (the "print server")? -- (2) Which OS and which version of CUPS is running on the other computers which detect the printer automatically (the "print clients")?

Comment: The "print server" is running Debian 9.6 with CUPS 2.2.1. The "print clients" have different versions of CUPS, but if it works with CUPS >= 2.2.7 it would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with adding my cups network-shared printer to a client that should use "Remote Printer" driver like an existing, working client already had. I eventually figured it out:

On the client, visit local cups (probably http://localhost:631). Navigate to administration -> add printer.

Select ipp printer type, and add your network printer: Mine was ipp://192.168.1.150:631/printers/ml1865. Add name, etc. Now, on the cups page where you select make and model or PPD file, select "Raw" -> IPP Everywhere. Then select button "Add Printer."